# API works locally and on vercel but not when hosted on GoDaddy server

Tags: node.js, api, next.js, backend, nodemailer

I have developed an API using nodemailer for a nextjs web app ,to send the submitted email to me and it works perfectly fine when running it locally and in Vercel hosting. However, when I create a build version and host it on my GoDaddy server, the API is not sending the email and instead throwing an error.

The api is to send a email-form to a my email.
the api code,

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { email } = req.body;

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "subscription@gmail.com",
      pass: "******....",
    },
  });

  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: "your-website",
    to: "mypersonal@gmail.com",
    subject: "New subscription",
    text: `${email}`,
  });

  console.log(`Message sent: ${info.messageId}`);

  res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
}
```

the api request in the front end code

```
const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

// emailsend
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [isValidEmail, setIsValidEmail] = useState(true);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();


const response = await fetch("/api/subscribe", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
});

if (response.ok) {
  console.log("Email sent successfully");
  toast.success("Thank you. We’ll keep you updated.");
} else {
  console.log("Error sending email");
  toast.error("Error sending email, Please try again");
}

setIsSubmitted(true);
};
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue and get the API working correctly on the GoDaddy server. Thank you!

Comment: "the API stops functioning correctly" means what?! Please take a moment and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.